# Программа кассир

Tags: python, python-3.x, консоль

Суть программы: у нас есть касса, которая продает билеты в кино за **25$** и каждый человек покупает один билет и у него есть **25$/50$/100$** одной купюрой. Суть в том, что вводится список с количеством денег у всех покупателей в очереди и прога сама высчитывает хватит ли ей налички, чтобы со всеми расплатиться или нет.

**Проблема в том, что почему-то крутиться бесконечный цикл.**

```
def tickets(people):
text = "YES"
length = len (people)
i = 0

cash_count = {25 : 0, 50 : 0, 100 : 0}

while i < length and text == "YES":

    banknote = people [i]

    for key in cash_count.keys():

        if banknote == key:
            cash = cash_count [key] 
            cash_count [key] = cash + 1

    if banknote == 25:

        if cash_count [25] > 0:
            cash = cash_count [25]
            cash_count [25] = cash - 0

        else:
            text = "NO"

    elif banknote == 50:

        if cash_count [25] > 0:
            cash = cash_count [25]
            cash_count [25] = cash - 1

        else:
            text = "NO"

    elif banknote == 100:

        if cash_count [50] > 0 and cash_count [25] > 0:
            cash = cash_count [50]
            cash_count [50] = cash - 1

            cash = cash_count [25]
            cash_count [25] = cash - 1

        elif cash_count [25] > 2:
            cash = cash_count [25]
            cash_count [25] = cash - 3

        else:
            text = "NO"
    else:
        print ("В массиве введенно неверное значение купюры.")
        
return count
```

Тестил вот, так:

```
print (tickets([25, 25, 50]), "YES")
print (tickets([25, 100]), "NO")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну как бы проблема очевидна. Ни `i`, ни `length` не изменяют своего значения, поэтому программа все время работает с элементом `people [0]`, не переходя к следующим.

Comment: Спасибо, рил заработало.

Comment: Пост не имеет смысловой нагрузки для комьюнити, поэтому удалю

Comment: А как нибудь закрыть из общего доступа можно ? А то удалить не получается.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question